# Javascript setTimeout function call with event argument?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

What is the best way to pull in the event object when using setTimeout? I'm using jQuery to handle normalizing the event model in all browsers, but I'm not sure how to get the 'e' object in to the checkPos function.

My current code:

```
function MouseDownEvent(e) {
    *snip*
    timeoutID = setTimeout(checkPos(e), 500);
}
function checkPos(e) {
    //function uses e on a timeout of 500ms
    timeoutID = setTimeout( checkPos(e) }, 500);
}
```

Currently that code works once because the function is called in the mousedown event, but never updates the e object as the user moves the mouse. The FF javascript error console also declares that it is 'a useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)', but following that advice causes it to completely fail.

How can I pull in the 'e' event argument from a setTimeout call?

Edit: Added in the code that reruns the checkPos function every 500ms

Comment: With your code, you're actually invoking `checkPos` when calling `setTimeout` (due to the function invocation operator `()`) and passing its return value to `setTimeout`; that value probably isn't a reference to a function, so `setTimeout` fails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly why are you using two timeouts? It looks to me like setInterval() would be better

```
function MouseDownEvent(e) {
 *snip*
 clearInterval(intervalID);
 intervalID = setInterval(function(){checkPos(e);}, 500);
}
```

Secondly could you please clarify this : "...but never updates the e object as the user moves the mouse." Why would the event object be updated when the user moves the mouse? You've only assigned a mouseDown handler. If you wanted to do something on every mouse move then you should use a mouseMove event, in which case the timeout / interval would be unnecessary anyway.

```
function MouseMoveEvent(e) {
 //called every time the mouse is moved, event object will contain position
}
```

As always in JavaScript you should look for an event driven solution first and only use timed handlers when you absolutely have to.

*Edit - addressing issues op raised in comments *

```
var handler = {
    i : 0,
    function : mouseMoveEvent(e) {
      handler.i++;
      if (handler.i % 100 == 0) {
        //Do expensive operations
      }
    }
}

$(myElement).bind("mousemove", handler.mouseMoveEvent);
```

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
function MouseDownEvent(e) {
    *snip*
    timeoutID = setTimeout(function(){checkPos(e);}, 500);
}
function checkPos(e) {
    //function uses e on a timeout of 500ms
}
```

**EDIT due to OP comments..**

To have access to an updated event each time checkPos is fired:

```
var myNamespace = {};

$('body').mousemove(function(e) {
    myNamespace.mouseEvent = e; 
});

function checkPos() {
    doSomethingWith(myNamespace.mouseEvent);
}

timerID = setInterval(checkPos, 500);
```

Comment: Sorry to back off on this answer, but when I re-ran this code putting checkPos(e); in, it failed to bring in the updated e event after each timeout.

Comment: It won't work with your edited code. This method forms a 'closure' over `e`. To access an updated event, you need to store the event somewhere that is accessible to the `checkPos` function (external to it), and update that stored event in the `MouseDownEvent` function.

Comment: There's no way to call the event object in javascript or jQuery such that I can pull in the current mouse position based on the timeout?

Comment: @C Bauer perhaps it would help if you explained why you need to use a timeout. Javascript has a MouseMove event for polling the mouse position, so I don't see why you'd want to use a timeout. See my answer for more.

Comment: @Ollie - The snip contains a loop and other code that would become a bottleneck if tied to say, the mousemove event, but it needs to fire regularly.

Comment: @C Bauer: you could tie into the mouse move event to just update `myNamespace.mousePos` or somesuch, and then have your function called on a timer...better to use `setInterval` too.

Comment: @C Bauer in this case I would create a wrapper object containing a counter and my event handlers. Each time the event handler is run increment the counter and only run your expensive code say every 100 iterations or whatever works for you. This is more efficient then using an interval as it won't fire unless the mouse is moved. I'll add this example to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a curry function, there is one for jQuery [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/curry).

Generally, you would have this:

```
function foo(a, b)
{
    alert(a + b);
}

var bar = curry(foo, 1);

bar(2); // alerts 3, as if you had called foo(1, 2)
```

so you could do:

```
setTimeout(curry(checkPos, e), 500);
```

Since curry returns a function with it's first argument bound to e, you can pass it straight into setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could see, IE won't allow to pass the "event" object around like you need.

The only workaround I can think of is storing whatever value you need in advance as global variable then check that variable in the delayed function.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/YvYtn/1/

This will show the last X position, you can store whatever you need from the event object.

The JS code:

```
var _lastPosX= null;
function MouseDownEvent(evt) {
    if (typeof evt == "undefined" || !evt)
        evt = window.event;
    _lastPosX = (evt.clientX || evt.pageX);
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout("checkPos();", 500);
}
function checkPos() {
    alert(_lastPosX);
}
```